# good/full Boot Spirit examples using version 2 syntax

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

Almost all of the examples I've gone and looked at so far from: http://boost-spirit.com/repository/applications/show_contents.php use the old syntax.  I've read and re-read the actual documentation at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/index.html and the examples therein.  I know Joel is starting a compiler series on the blog http://boost-spirit.com/home/ but that hasn't gotten in full swing yet.  Any other resources to see worked examples using some more sophisticated/involved aspects in the context of fully working applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is always the examples directory in Boost SVN: $BOOST_ROOT/libs/spirit/example containing a couple of more sophisticated things to look at. The tests directory adjacent to this contains a huge amount of small tests scrutinizing each and every technique we know of as well.

In addition, Joel and I will have a presentation about the progress we made with the compiler thing you mentioned at [BoostCon](http://www.boostcon.com/program/sessions#de-guzman-kaiser-rad-spirit) next week. All of the material will be available right after the talk and all the related code is already in the examples directory in Boost SVN (trunk). We probably will start writing about this effort on the [Spirit](http://boost-spirit.com/home/) website after the conference.

I know this is not as much as we have for Spirit.Classic in the application repository, but we really hope to get there over time... Everything depends on what will get contributed by the people using Spirit!

Comment: Fair enough.  You started posting about the compiler so that is probably what I'll spend my time looking at next.  I was hoping maybe that there was a different repo for the new version syntax but I guess I'll have to wait on people using it (or get something working myself).